# Google Compute Engine shows a thunder icon on the console

Tags: google-compute-engine

I cannot create a VM instance on Google Compute Engine (my project uses a starter pack).
I have a thunder icon on the console, and no button to create an instance.

For my other project, I haven't had this problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page? It disappeared on me after refreshing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you got billing enabled?

With starter packs/Google credit, you still need to have billing enabled, the credits/discount get applied on the billing date.